# How to push the matrix of values in sorting by key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, key

I have written this function. It takes sequence of indexes and matrix of values. For example,

```
path=[1, 0, 2]
matr = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 5], [1, 10, 1]]
```

It means that our distance is `m[1][0]+m[0][2]`=0+3=3.

I have the list of paths which I want to sort by distance. How can I do this if it requires value of matr? I attempt to do this: `list_of_paths.sort(key=distance(matr))`

```
def distance(path, matr):
dist = 0
    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        dist += matr[path[i]][path[i+1]]
    return dist
```

Comment: How about: list_of_paths.sort(key=lambda p: distance(p, matr))

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `path` list sorted using `zip()` built-in inside the custom function:

```
def distance(p):
    matr = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 5], [1, 10, 1]]
    s = 0
    for x, y in zip(p, p[1:]):
        s += matr[x][y]
    return s

path = [[1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
print(sorted(path, key=distance))

# [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1]]    <- Output
#      2          3          13        <- in the increasing order of distance.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance(path):
     # matr available from global name space
    return sum([matr[path[i]][path[i+1]] for i in range(len(path)-1)])

matr = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 5], [1, 10, 1]]
list_of_paths =[[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
list_of_paths.sort(key=distance)
print(list_of_paths)
```

Result: [[1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]]

Comment: Your comment under my question is the best! Thank you